# Can we set the Application insights filter property values through c# code?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Can we set filter property values through C# code?

Please find attached image.

I guess this will help full

[image]

I hope u people understand
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Wow, so much is obscured I can't even see what it is you are trying to filter. In this case a thousand words is better than one picture.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling You can filter or modify any values using TelemetryProcessors/TelemetryInitializers as explained in the doc.

Comment: which project are you using? if it's web application, it's easy to set via TelemetryInitializers.